# What is this Eclipse view and how to implement it in other Eclipse-based products?

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder

In Flash Builder 4.6's code assist, there is this extra box on the right of the classes, outlined in red, (image: http://oi42.tinypic.com/rqyuqq.jpg) that pops up when using the default Flex SDK. What is it called?

I find this feature very useful and wondering where I can get more information to implement a similar one in another Eclipsed-based IDE that I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this window is called JavaDoc View

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fref-view-javadoc.htm

any developer that uses the eclipse IDE knows this windows, it's shown the javadoc content of selected element,

it's part of Eclipse Java development tools (JDT)